# request uri redirect ignore subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the htaccess code below being used to redirect mobile devices to the mobile page of a site. However, I need it to not redirect if it is a subdomain URL; ex: subdomain.mydomain.com
What change(s) do I need to make?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/mobile-page.html [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
```

So that in orde for the redirect to occur, the requested host doesn't start with a **www**, and it has a subdomain in front of `mydomain.com` (that's not **www**, via the first condition). So you're rules will look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/mobile-page.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. When on the iPhone, subdomain.mydomain.com goes to the mobile version, and mydomain.com goes to the full (non-mobile) version.

Comment: @spiderling sorry, I misread your question. Move the `!` from in front fof the "www" to the condition below it.

Comment: subdomain is working properly - thanks, but the main domain was still going to the full version. So I removed the first condition you provided, and it is now working for both scenarios.